# kernel: decmpfs repeated error messages origin?

Tags: time-machine, anti-virus, compression

I am in the process of evaluating different anti-virus on Mac OS X
(Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite…).
Upon running a full scan to test Sophos on a Mountain Lion Mac I witnessed a total slow down of this scan without any error, hint or explanation.

Hence I searched the standard system log file to see what this hidden problem might be coming from.

I have a lot of repeated sequences of error messages coming from `decmpfs` which are time related:

```
Aug 16 01:22:01 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Backing up to: /Volumes/••my backup volume••/Backups.backupdb
Aug 16 01:22:01 ••my Mac•• kernel[0]: /SourceCache/AppleFSCompression_kexts/AppleFSCompression-49/Compressors/Dataless/compressorType5Kext.c:532: Error: post_request error for /Volumes/••my backup volume••/Backups.backupdb/••my Mac••/2015-07-23-080243/••my Mac root volume••/.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/2a/com.apple.documentVersions/B15D3CEE-6DAA-4EB2-AD77-B8EBD67CBD41.pages: 35
Aug 16 01:22:01 ••my Mac•• kernel[0]: decmpfs.c:1339:decmpfs_read_compressed: decmpfs_fetch_uncompressed_data err -35
Aug 16 01:22:06 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Using file event preflight for ••my Mac root volume••
Aug 16 01:22:06 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Will copy (445 KB) from ••my Mac root volume••
Aug 16 01:22:06 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Found 41 files (445 KB) needing backup
Aug 16 01:22:06 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: 1.83 GB required (including padding), 5.53 GB available
Aug 16 01:22:16 ••my Mac•• kernel[0]: /SourceCache/AppleFSCompression_kexts/AppleFSCompression-49/Compressors/Dataless/compressorType5Kext.c:532: Error: post_request error for /Volumes/••my backup volume••/Backups.backupdb/••my Mac••/2015-07-23-080243/••my Mac root volume••/.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/2a/com.apple.documentVersions/B15D3CEE-6DAA-4EB2-AD77-B8EBD67CBD41.pages: 35
Aug 16 01:22:16 ••my Mac•• kernel[0]: decmpfs.c:1339:decmpfs_read_compressed: decmpfs_fetch_uncompressed_data err -35
Aug 16 01:22:32 ••my Mac•• kernel[0]: /SourceCache/AppleFSCompression_kexts/AppleFSCompression-49/Compressors/Dataless/compressorType5Kext.c:532: Error: post_request error for /Volumes/••my backup volume••/Backups.backupdb/••my Mac••/2015-07-23-080243/••my Mac root volume••/.DocumentRevisions-V100/PerUID/501/2b/com.apple.documentVersions/025F1963-3BA9-4B0B-ADFD-4E51082CC82B.pages: 35
Aug 16 01:22:32 ••my Mac•• kernel[0]: decmpfs.c:1339:decmpfs_read_compressed: decmpfs_fetch_uncompressed_data err -35
Aug 16 01:22:37 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Copied 1379 files (462 KB) from volume ••my Mac root volume••.
Aug 16 01:22:39 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Using file event preflight for ••my Mac root volume••
Aug 16 01:22:39 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Will copy (Zero KB) from ••my Mac root volume••
Aug 16 01:22:39 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Found 6 files (Zero KB) needing backup
Aug 16 01:22:39 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: 1.83 GB required (including padding), 5.53 GB available
Aug 16 01:22:43 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Copied 155 files (153 bytes) from volume ••my Mac root volume••.
Aug 16 01:22:44 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Created new backup: 2015-08-16-012243
Aug 16 01:22:44 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Starting post-backup thinning
Aug 16 01:22:44 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: No post-back up thinning needed: no expired backups exist
Aug 16 01:22:44 ••my Mac•• com.apple.backupd[54217]: Backup completed successfully.
```

I made a research within the Apple Knowledge Base and found nothing.
I found a lot of discussions about this kind of errors on Apple discussions groups. But nothing the level above discussion.

A time back analysis of my `/var/log/system.log.*.bz2` shows that I never had such a kernel error within 7 days before and that the first one occured at the exact time of starting my 1st scan with Sophos.

---

What are these error messages caused by (Time Machine, kernel, Sophos)?

What do they mean?

Comment: Do you encounter such slow-downs also after **disabling** archive scan in Sophos? Additionally you may try to remove the temp folder Sophos uses to unarchive compressed files from being backed-up by Time Machine (i don't know if such a folder exists though, i may have to explore that).

Comment: The "Scan: ☐ Inside archives and compredssed files" was set to off.